# Why KNN implementation in weka runs faster?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, knn, text-classification

1) As we know KNN perform no computation in training phase instead defer all computations for classification because of which we call it lazy learner. It should take more time in classification than training however i found this assumption almost opposite about weka. In which KNN take more time in training than testing.

Why and how KNN in weka perform much faster in classification whereas in general it should perform slower ?

Does it also result in computations mistake ?

2) When we say feature weighting in Knn may improve performance for high dimensional data, what do we mean by saying it ? Do we mean that feature selection and selecting feature with high InformationGain ?

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to question 1**

My guess is that the Weka implementation uses some kind of data structure to efficiently perform (approximate) nearest-neighbor queries.

Using such data structures, queries can be performed much more efficiently than performing them in the naive way.

Examples of such data structures are the [KD tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and the [SR Tree](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/katayama_norio_1997_2/katayama_norio_1997_2.pdfal%20Nearest%20Neighbor%20Queries).

In the training phase the data structure has to be created, so it will take more time than classification.

**Answer to question 2**

(I'm not sure if you refer to ***predictive performance*** or performance as in ***speed-up***. Since both are relevant, I will address them both in my answer.)

Using higher weights for the most relevant features and lower weights for the less relevant features may improve the ***predictive performance***.

Another way to improve ***predictive performance*** is to perform feature selection. Using [Mutual Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) or some other kind of univariate association (like [Pearson correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) for continuous variables) is the simplest and easiest way to perform feature selection. Note that reducing the number of variables can offer a significant ***speed-up*** in terms of ***computational time***.

Of course, you can do both, that is, perform feature selection first and then use weights on the remaining features. You could for example use the mutual information to weight the remaining features. In case of text-classification, you could also use TF-IDF to weight your features.

Comment: It's also not clear what the 'training' phase means other than building the neighborhood data structure. Since this is a lazy learning algorithm as the OP comments, then there is no set of parameters to fit or calibrate during any kind of training phase. You simply calculate things about any incoming observation (whether you want to call it a "training" observation or not) against the set of data that constitutes the classifier.

Comment: @George, thanx for passing through, Can you kindly elaborate a little more your 2nd answer as one way is to remove irrelevant feature through feature selection via information gain etc it may also improve performance, Somewhere i have read to multiply the weight of a feature to its frequency(TF-IDF) which may also make a feature with more weight to be more important. Thanx in advance :)

Comment: @EMS well the things which make me more worry is K-Neighbors, even if we assume that it implements an efficient data structure inside as George said even then in classification calculating distance for 10(K=10) neighbors should take more time than fitting a margin function (SVM) but what i have observed is that both are almost same. Unless we saw whats comming we cannot determine its neighbors